# Deriving explicit formula from recursion related to Skyscrapers

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Define $S(n,k)$ as the number of permutations of $1,2,\ldots,n$ such that if you had buildings of these height in a line, you would see $k$ of them. E.g. from the permutation $2,1,4,3$ you would see the buildings of height $2$ and $4$, while the buildings of height $1$ and $3$ are covered by the buildings of height $2$ and $4$ respectively. Find an explicit formula for $S(n,k)$.

So I first found a recursive formula. We can place the $n$th building in any of the spots so that there are $i\in[0,n-1]$ spots in front of it. The $n-1-i$ buildings behind it will not be seen. So we can choose which $i$ of the $n-1-i$ buildings will be placed in front of the $n$th building. There are $S(i,k-1)$ ways to arrange those. There are $(n-1-i)!$ ways to arrange the other buildings. So we have the recursion
$$S(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}(n-1-i)!S(i,k-1)$$
$$S(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{i!}S(i,k-1)$$
From here I wasn't sure what to do. I thought there might be some generating function solution, so I defined $s(n,k)=\frac{S(n,k)}{n!}$. And then manipulated the recursion
$$s(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}s(i,k-1)$$
Since I couldn't figure out anything with generating functions, I instead followed through with the recursion to get that
$$s(n,k)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{0<a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_{k-1}<n} \frac{1}{a_1a_2\ldots a_{k-1}}$$
I couldn't figure out where to go from here, but I did get a loose approximation of $s(n,k)=\frac{\left(H_{k-1}\right)^{n-1}}{n(k-1)!}$ which I think is not useful for $k$ close to $n$

Comment: If you calculate $S(n,k)$ explicitly for several small values of $n$ and $k$, you will see that $S(n,k)$ is equal to a certain famous combinatorial function. For a further hint, try computing the sums $S(n,1)+\dots+S(n,n)$ for small $n$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Ahh I see, stirling numbers of the first kind; I haven't really learned too much about those. I do see that $\sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k)=n!$ trivially

Comment: Oh yeah, $S(n,1)+\dots+S(n,n)$ was not a super helpful hint. Anyways, there aren't any formulas for $S(n,k)$ nicer than the one in your post (you can see some other options on Wikipedia).